# Taking advantage of ES6 in a child process

Tags: node.js, electron, babeljs

I have a node.js project built upon [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue), which utilizes electron, babel, webpack, and vue. I have built a simple vue SPA, but I have found that the single-threaded nature doesn't sit well with the large amount of data fetching and processing that it needs to do.

My first idea was to create child processes. I created a vue component that spawns and manages the child process:

```
startProcess() {
            const path          = require('path');
            const fs            = require('fs');
            const child_process = require('child_process');
            const app_root      = require('app-root-path');

            const service_root  = '/src/main/services/';

            const service_path = app_root.resolve(path.format({dir: service_root, name: this.service, ext: '.js'}));

            if (fs.existsSync(service_path)) {

                this.service_process = child_process.fork(service_path, [], { silent: true });

                this.service_process.on('close', this.onChildClose);
                this.service_process.on('error', this.onChildError);
                this.service_process.on('disconnect', this.onChildDisconnect);
                this.service_process.on('message', this.onChildMessage);

                this.service_process.send({ message: "hello" });

                console.log(`${this.service} started successfully`);

            } else {
                console.log(`${service_path} does not exist`);
                console.log(`${this.service} cannot start!`);
            }
        }
```

And my example process:

```
const path = require('path');
const service = path.basename(__filename);

process.on('disconnect', (m) => {
    console.log(`${service} disconnected, exiting...`);
    process.exit();
});

process.on('exit', (m) => {
    console.log(`${service} has stopped`);
});

process.on('message', (m) => {
    if (m.message === "ping") {
        process.send({message:"pong"});
    } else {
    }
    console.log(`parent > ${service}:`, m);
});

function tick()
{
    //process.send({ message: `${service} update` });

}

setInterval(tick, 500);
```

This works surprisingly well. The IPC allows me to pump messages to/from each child process, allowing me to delegate large data tasks across multiple processes. However, there's one snag.

I'm unable to use ES6 features in the child process.

For example, attempting to  `import` and `export` classes causes an error. By running these child processes using `babel-node`, they appear to work properly, but I would instead prefer not to have babel separately installed from my app. According to http://node.green, these should be compatible under nodejs v8.1.2.

How can I take advantage of these features? Is there any better way to structure my app for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import` and `export` is not a part of es6 spec right now. See this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53) for details. Thats why node doesnot support it. Even at http://node.green there is no this feature.

Comment: It is part of the ES6 spec, but it has not been implemented in Node yet. You can find more on this issue [here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c)

Comment: In addition to that, Electron uses v7.4.0.